# Не корректно срабатывает JS с Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Есть простенький скрипт для перемещения объектов с определением положения мыши (parallax). Вопросов два:

1) Почему не перемещается первое изображение в `<section>` (основная проблема)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Пробовал переписать код под jQuery, так как она все равно подключена. Но, по объему получился код больше и работать отказался. Скорее всего перемудрил. Если кто поможет с этим делом, буду признателен. Но, основной вопрос первый.

Спасибо

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".layer");

let sx = 0;
let sy = 0;

let dx = sx;
let dy = sy;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove);

function onMove(e) {
  sx = e.clientX - (window.innerWidth / 2);
  sy = e.clientY - (window.innerHeight / 2);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, (el, index) => {
    dx = sx * 0.003 * index * -1;
    dy = sy * 0.001 * index * -1;
    
    el.style.transform = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`;
  });  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/972352/background.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

img:nth-child(1) { 
  z-index: 4;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
img:nth-child(4) {
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/972352/layer-1.png" class="layer" />
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/972352/layer-2.png" class="layer" />
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/972352/layer-3.png" class="layer" />
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/972352/layer-4.png" class="layer" />
  </section>
</main>
```